# I can't get all the <a> tags in selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I need to get all the text inside the `<a>` tags, but I can get only the text of the first `<a>` tag.

Here is my code:

```
table_page = driver2.find_elements_by_class_name('paging')
for tn in table_page: 
    num = tn.find_element_by_class_name('paper.page_link')
    print(num.text)
```

and this is the HTML code:

```
<div class="paging">
    <em class=" link_page" style="cursor:pointer"> 1 </em>
    <a class="paper page_link" href="javascript:" url="./detail_nbid" page_num="2">2</a>
    <a class="paper page_link" href="javascript:" url="./detail_nbid" page_num="3">3</a>
</div>
```

what I expected is `2, 3` but I get only `2`.

Comment: I believe there is a typo in your CSS Selector or the html code, which I am assuming is just a transfer error, because it doesn't explain the issue.

Comment: No  typo just finding a single element instead of them all.tn.find_element should be tn.find_elements instead and then loop and print.

Comment: You sure? "pager.page_link" is looking for <pager> elements with "page_link" in it's class attribute

Comment: @ArundeepChohan then I get 'list' object has no attribute 'text' error. how do I solve this problem?

Comment: @goalie1998 I double checked html code but there was no typo.

Comment: try find_elements_by_css_selector('a.paper')

Comment: You sure about that? The edit history says otherwise...

Comment: @goalie1998 sorry, I realized and fixed it. Thank you but I still can't solve this problem

Comment: @Hyuk small example for 1 class vs many with print all a tags.

Comment: solved it thank u guys

Answer (score 1):

If you [select by class name](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-class-name), then you can only specify a class name. This doesn't give you the required flexibility you need here.

Try selecting by [CSS Selector](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors).

Here, you are interested in `a` tags with the `class`'s `paper` and `page_link`.

For example:

```
for a in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.paper.page_link'):
    print(a.text)
```

Output:

```
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

There is typo in your html code. in href your " are not matching.

```
<div class="paging">
    <em class="link_page" style="cursor:pointer;"> 1 </em>
    <a class="paper page_link" href="javascript:url='./detail_nbid'" page_num="2">2</a>
    <a class="paper page_link" href="javascript:url='./detail_nbid'" page_num="3">3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all a tags in all  paging classes.

```
table_page = driver2.find_elements_by_class_name('paging')
for tn in table_page: 
    nums = tn.find_elements_by_class_name('paper.page_link')
    for num in nums:
        print(num.text)
```

Otherwise

```
table_page = driver2.find_element_by_class_name('paging')
nums = table_page.find_elements_by_class_name('paper.page_link')
for num in nums:
    print(num.text)
```